# How to add class to table row depending on condition rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table with Entries. Each entry has a datetime, text, calory. I need to make all rows green, if total calories for that day is less than expecting value, otherwise make it red. In my index action I have @total (which is the value to compare with) and in the end I have two arrays with good (green) dates and bad dates.

```
def index
@entries = Entry.all
@total = 50
@total2 = Entry.all
@a = {}
Entry.all.each do |entry|
  if @a.key?(entry.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[0..10])
    @a[entry.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[0..10]] += (entry.calory)
  else  
    @a[entry.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[0..10]] = 0
    @a[entry.time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[0..10]] += entry.calory
  end
end
@good = []
@bad = []
@a.each do |c|
  if c[1] < @total
    @good.append(c[0])
  else
    @bad.append(c[0])
  end
end
```

end

Then in my index.html.erb I loop through the rows and try to change it's color, if the value is in good or bad array. But it colors everything green.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var a = '<%=@a%>';
  var final = '<%=@final%>';
  var good = '<%=@good%>';
  var bad = '<%=@bad%>';
  console.log(good);
  $('#entries tr').each(function() {
    var date = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
    if (good.substring(date) !== -1) {
      $(this).find("td:first-child").addClass('good');
    } else {
      $(this).find("td:first-child").addClass('bad');
    }
});

</script>
```

Here is my table

```
Time    Text    Calory  Show    Edit    Destroy 
2016-12-24 10:00:00 first   23  Show    Edit    Destroy
2016-12-24 11:58:00 second  45  Show    Edit    Destroy
2016-12-24 12:59:00 third   56  Show    Edit    Destroy
2016-12-28 12:29:00 sds 34  Show    Edit    Destroy
2016-12-24 10:00:00 dewq    34  Show    Edit    Destroy
```

Here is console.log(good): ["2016-12-28 "]
Here is console.log(bad): ["2016-12-24 "]

Here is console.log(date) for each date:

```
2016-12-24 10:00:00
2016-12-24 11:58:00
2016-12-24 12:59:00
2016-12-28 12:29:00
2016-12-24 10:00:00
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(good);` and `console.log(date);`

Comment: @Hackerman done

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do it in javascript. I think you could use erb's helper to do it.

Comment: @bananaappletw how can I make it?

Comment: in erb just give your tr the class `good` or `bad` depending in which array the data is

Comment: @Fallenhero but how can I check this data?

Comment: I would collect the entry ids in your array (just use one, for example bad). Then check `@bad.include?(entry.id)`

Comment: Look at this example, IMHO you just need `indexOf` : https://jsfiddle.net/e0sn1d0k/

Comment: @Hackerman It goes red.

Comment: So it works, right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `indexOf`; based on your sample data this should works:

```
$('#entries tr').each(function() {
   var date = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
   if(date.indexOf(bad[0].toString()) > -1){
     $(this).find("td:first-child").addClass('bad');
   }
   if(date.indexOf(good[0].toString()) > -1){
     $(this).find("td:first-child").addClass('good');
   }
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0sn1d0k/3/

Comment: But I need them to go red when sum of the calories for that day is more than value. For example, here all records 2016-12-24 should become red and 2016-12-28 should become green.